# Eclipse invisible menu text

Tags: eclipse, gtk3, gtk2, eclipse-mars, eclipse-neon

In some Eclipse versions (at least Mars and Neon) some texts and checkboxes are invisible for some Linux Desktop Environments (Kubuntu + KDE, Mint + xfce).

How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Can you see those elements when you run Eclipse on GTK2? For testing, set `SWT_GTK3=0` in the shell from where you launch Eclipse. See also http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html?cp=2_1_5_0 and search for GTK.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

The Problem stems from the used [GTK+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B) (Gtk3) version used.

I had the same problem and solved it by applying the solution suggested by the User Potomac from this [forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200053) after I followed the suggestion in the comment of StackOverflow User @stephanHerrmann

> you can try this workaround :
>
> edit the file /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini,
>   and add these 2 lines before the line "--launcher.appendVmargs" :
>
> --launcher.GTK_version 
>   2
>
> after this modification it's the version "2" of gtk launcher who will be used, the GUI will be much better and the background of tooltips will have a correct color